# Remove post date on my pages

Tags: tumblr

Immediately after my `{block:Posts}` I have placed a date that will display the post date on top of every post I make. But I realized this piece of code is also rendered on my *Pages* as well and thus produces unwanted commas and `<br/>`s. How can I let Tumblr know that I only want these dates to appear on my main blog page and not in any other pages?

**Update:**

```
     {block:Text}
<strong>{DayOfWeek}, {DayOfMonth} {Month} {Year}</strong>
                <br/><br/>
                    <div class="text post">

                        {block:Title}
                        <h2><div class="textposttitles">{Title}</div></h2>

                        {/block:Title}

                        {Body}
                        {block:IndexPage} 
                        <div class="permalink">
                        <p class="date">
                            <a href="{Permalink}"> {NoteCountWithLabel}</a></p>
                        </div>
                        {/block:IndexPage}
                    </div>

                {/block:Text}
```

Comment: Wrap it inside the posts block?

Comment: @AndyHolmes you mean put them inside '{block:Posts}' and '{/block:Posts}' tags. They are already immediately after '{block:Posts}'. And it does not work. Can you explain with code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Date Block and Variables**

Currently the OP is using just the date variables, without the block. The block checks to see if the post has a date, and then render its.

As pages don't have a date, the block check fails and the date isn't rendered.

```
{block:Posts}
{block:Date}
<strong>{DayOfWeek}, {DayOfMonth} {Month} {Year}</strong>
{/block:Date}
{/block:Posts}
```

On a sidenote, the `{block:Date}` is a handy way to render markup (shares, comments, etc) specific to posts only.

**Reference**

Date Operators https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#dates

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working anymore - are you aware of any changes to the API that might be causing the date block to show up on non-post pages?

Comment: The API has no impact on theme operators. The code works as expected. `{block:Date}` has to be inside the post loop. I would suggest posting a new question if you feel you still have an issue.

Comment: There is currently a bug on Tumblr that's preventing the {block:Date} variable from working as expected. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84781/how-to-hide-date-on-tumblr-pages/84865#84865

Comment: The answer still stands as the code is correct. It would be handy to remove your comments once the bug is fixed to avoid confusion for others.